# How to ignore a field from serializing when using circe in scala

Tags: scala, circe

I am using circe in scala and have a following requirement :

Let's say I have some class like below and I want to avoid password field from being serialised then is there any way to let circe know that it should not serialise password field?

In other libraries we have annotations like @transient which prevent field from being serialised ,is there any such annotation in circe?

```
case class Employee(                   
                     name: String,
                     password: String)
```

Comment: https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a custom encoder that redacts some fields:

```scala
implicit val encodeEmployee: Encoder[Employee] = new Encoder[Employee] {
  final def apply(a: Employee): Json = Json.obj(
    ("name", Json.fromString(a.name)),
    ("password", Json.fromString("[REDACTED]")),
  )
}
```

**LATER UPDATE**

In order to avoid going through all fields contramap from a semiauto/auto decoder:

```scala
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._

implicit val encodeEmployee: Encoder[Employee] =
  deriveEncoder[Employee]
    .contramap[Employee](unredacted => unredacted.copy(password = "[REDACTED]"))
```

Comment: if I have 100 fields in the class, do I need to specify how to handle each field?

Comment: @Hitesh i've updated my answer with another approach

Answer (score 1):

Although @gatear's answer is useful, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Unfortunately Circe (at least until version 0.14.2) does not have annotations to ignore fields. So far there is only a single annotation (`@JsonKey`) and this is used to rename field names.

In order to ignore a field when serialising (which Circe calls encoding) you can avoid that field in the `Encoder` implementation.

So instead of including the `password` field:

```scala
implicit val employeeEncoder: Encoder[Employee] =
  Encoder.forProduct2("name", "password")(employee => (employee.name, employee.password))
```

you ommit it:

```scala
implicit val employeeEncoder: Encoder[Employee] =
  Encoder.forProduct1("name")(employee => (u.name))
```

Alternatively what I've been using is creating a smaller `case class` which only includes the fields I'm interested in. Then I let Circe's automatic derivation kick in with `io.circe.generic.auto._`:

```scala
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._

case class EmployeeToEncode(name: String)

// Then given an employee object:
EmployeeToEncode(employee.name).asJson
```

Answer (score 1):

```
deriveEncoder.mapJsonObject(_.remove("password"))
```